# "POST getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" error when using bot emulator

Tags: botframework

I am not able to connect locally with the help of bot emulator.
I always get the error:

> POST getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND lall lall:80

I am using the .Net Bot Framework.

Note : I tried with locale field blank. Even then it's giving the same error.

**Screenshot of the Error Message**:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the details of the parameters you are using in emulator? Add a screenshot for example (just avoid showing password)

Comment: what is the URL you are trying to access in the emulator

Comment: The URL is  http://localhost:3979/api/messages

Comment: Why are you setting a port in Locale field in the emulator?

Comment: “Locale” should be blank

Comment: I tried with locale field blank. Even then it's giving the same error.Is it a DNS error??

Comment: @SaurabhLall you may be connecting to internet from office network. try connecting to internet from your mobile hot spot or personal network.

Comment: @rajesh even with other nework it gives same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I got it working by setting up my proxy variables http_proxy and https_proxy.
HTTP_PROXY=username:password@myproxy:myproxyport 
HTTPS_PROXY=username:password@myproxy:myproxyport